# Why are there boxes in returns in text files (Python 3x)

Tags: python-3.x, file

I'm working on multiple highscores right now and I have the scores.txt file set up like this so far:
`1651
231
54`

But, when I test it, it shows up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6nYi.png).

Why does that happen and how can I fix it?
Here is the code that it happens in:

```
#high score
    line1 = 0
    line2 = 0
    line3 = 0
    with open("Assets\scores.txt") as multiple_hscore:
        multiple_hscore.seek(0)
        line1 = multiple_hscore.readline(10)
        line2 = multiple_hscore.readline(30)
        line3 = multiple_hscore.readline(50)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

P.S. I've tried doing \n and using strings and a few other things but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings you're reading from your file have some kind of non-printable character at the end of them, which your GUI library is rendering as a box. The most likely reason for that is that that's how it displays newline characters, since it can't lay out multiple lines of text for you.

You can probably fix the issue by calling `strip()` on each line you read:

```
with open("Assets\scores.txt") as multiple_hscore:
    line1 = multiple_hscore.readline(10).strip()
    line2 = multiple_hscore.readline(30).strip()
    line3 = multiple_hscore.readline(50).strip()
```

You could also be more explicit about what you want to strip and do something like `.rstrip('\n')`, but unless spaces could be a relevant part of your data, it's probably not necessary.

Note that seeking to position `0` in a newly opened file is not necessary. You'll normally start at that position unless you opened the file in mode `'a'` (which will seek to the end for you, since it's "append" mode).

Comment: Thank you so much!